# Wordpress language depending geographical zone

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to know if there was a possibility to change the language of your landing-page on Wordpress depending the geographical zone?
Here is my problem : My company is selling an app in France, UK and USA but we cannot distinguish the language English (UK) and English (USA) on WP and adjust the appropriate pricing (pounds or dollars). Thus, I'd like to adapt my landing-pages depending the geographic zone of my visitors. Is there a specific tool to use or a plugin?
Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Perfect Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

how about this one? https://wpml.org/forums/topic/how-to-detect-ip-location-and-automatically-display-local-language/

the words for your google search would have been: wordpress select language based on country ip

Answer (score 0):

In Woocommerce I've been using an extension called "WooCommerce Price Based on Country" which automatically detects the country of the visitor and shows the correct prices (they can be set manually or use an exchange rate). The URL is:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-price-based-on-countries/

For multi-language functionality I use Polylang (https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/).